# ArangoDB Webinterface - Coloring nodes

Tags: arangodb

How can I specify the colors of the nodes in a graph based on the different collection types? E.g.: There is a collection named `user` and all nodes of this type should have the same color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible, you can only define colors based on node's attributes.
if you are in need of this feature please raise a feature request on github.